# what error is this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < when using eval in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax-error

i've got a simple ajax call:

```
function message(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/file/timestamp="+ timestamp,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            var json = eval('('+data+')');
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
}
```

and i get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` at this line: `var json = eval('('+data+')');`

any ideas?

thanks.

edit:
some more details from the error:

```
$.ajax.successajax.js:9
f.Callbacks.njquery.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery.js:2
wjquery.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

here is some php if is helping

```
public function fileAction()
{
    $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender();

    $filename = '/test/text.txt';

    $front  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $data   = $front->getRequest()->getParams();

    $lastModif      = !empty($data['timestamp']) ? $data['timestamp'] : 0;
    $currentModif   = filemtime($filename);

    while($currentModif <= $lastModif){
        usleep(10000);
        clearstatcache();
        $currentModif = filemtime($filename);
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['msg'] = file_get_contents($filename);
    $response['timestamp'] = $currentModif;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

if i run this action i get json: `{"msg":"message","timestamp":1331599879}` but for some reason the response is not this but some html

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting XML and not JSON.

Comment: If you *are* getting JSON, `eval` is both unnecessary (jQuery parses the JSON for you) and Evil.

Comment: console.log(data) shows what? I am guessing an html error page.

Comment: yes, bit no error, just html for some reason.

Comment: Well figure that out and maybe your json will start appearing. Get Fiddler and see what the request/response is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what's inside `data`.  You're running `eval`, so whatever's in `data` is being run. Please post the `data` here,.

Comment: for some reason `data` has a bunch of html inside. Maybe there is my problem

Comment: @Patrioticcow: Yep. It's trying to evaluate the HTML. Obviously, it will see too many `<` and `>`s in the wrong place. WHat's the functionality you want? Shouldn't `var json=data` or `var json="("+data+")"` work? Or if you really want to use `eval`, try `eval("var json='"+data+"';");`

Comment: i edited my post and i was doing this `var json = eval('('+data+')');` to convert data to an array. I should have get back `{"msg":"message","timestamp":1331599879}` but instead i get a bunch of html

Answer (score 2):

What are you expecting to be returned in as data? Running eval will try to execute (data) which doesn't seem like it will be proper javascript. If you just want to store a string you can do:

```
var json = "(" + data + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

jholloman almost had it...

```
var json = eval("(" + data.responseText + ")");
```